# How to get how many items are visible on screen if MatSelctionList?

Tags: angular, typescript, list, angular-material

I want to know in code how many items are shown inside the material selection list on the screen.

I tried to use:

```ts
@ViewChild(MatSelectionList) matSelectionList: MatSelectionList;
```

But I did not see any variable or function with that information. Does anyone have a similar issue?

The purpose of that is simple: I have file explorer in my app and when I go a level up, I need to know how many elements there are.

Comment: It's not possible to check for that particular node array length?

Comment: Maybe, yes, but don't have idea how.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official documentation of `<mat-selection-list>`
https://run.stackblitz.com/api/angular/v1?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist-selection-example.ts

```
<mat-selection-list #shoes>
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let shoe of typesOfShoes">
    {{shoe}}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>

<p>
  Options selected: {{shoes.selectedOptions.selected.length}}
</p>
```

Comment: But how to get info about visible units, even unselected

Answer (score 0):

The `MatSelectionList` class offers the `options` variable which exposes the current options in the selection list.

From the [API documentation for `MatSelectionList`](https://material.angular.io/components/list/api#MatSelectionList):

> `options: QueryList<MatListOption>`
>
> The option components contained within this selection-list.

The `QueryList` class is a class from the `@angular/core` package and is documented on [Angular's API docs](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList).

Here's a description of the `QueryList` class:

> An unmodifiable list of items that Angular keeps up to date when the state of the application changes.

Here's an example of how to access the current list of options:

```html
<mat-selection-list #filesList>
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let file of files">
    <!-- ... -->
  </mat-list-option>
```

```js
export class MyComponent {
  @ViewChild('filesList', { static: true }) filesList: MatSelectionList;

  getOptions() {
    console.log('Current options:', this.filesList.options);
  }
}
```

Here's a [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-selection-list-get-options).

---

EDIT: If you only want to know the *length* of the current options, you can use the read-only [`QueryList.length`](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList#length) property:

```js
export class MyComponent {
  @ViewChild('filesList', { static: true }) filesList: MatSelectionList;

  getOptions() {
    console.log('Current number of options:', this.filesList.options.length);
  }
}
```

And if you want to retrieve the current options ASAP, you can check the current options in the [`AfterViewInit`](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) lifecycle hook:

```js
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('filesList', { static: true }) filesList: MatSelectionList;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('Current number of options:', this.filesList.options.length);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, it's looks fine but i need to get info how many rows i have right after page is load, if i try to get this info in ngOnInit or Constructor, i getting error: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined - do you know how to avoid that?

Comment: You have to access it in `ngAfterViewInit` as that is when the `ViewChild` reference resolves.

Comment: Even if i add it as action under a click it still returning undefined. Hmmm

Comment: Could you try to reproduce your problem in a StackBlitz?

Comment: I tried but i failed: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tsxmvo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html - can't make it work even close to my app (html is 100% accurate atm)

Comment: Man, change this and it works: `@ViewChild('filesList', { static: true }) filesList: MatSelectionList;` to this  `@ViewChild('fileElementsList') fileElementsList: MatSelectionList;`

Comment: Ok, it works only under action, when i try get this info from ngOnInit - get error, ngAfterViewInit - nothing :(

Comment: It's because the view still hasn't been instantiated in the `OnInit` lifecycle hook. I suggest that you should read up on Angular's lifecycle hooks from the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: And you have to make sure that the name of the view reference in your component's template is exactly the same as the reference string in your component's code.

Comment: I already read this yesterday but didn't find solution how i can make it work as i want.

Comment: @Yamdi Your StackBlitz has way too much complicated logic - for a start, why are you placing grid tiles within a list? I'm pretty sure that grid lists within lists are not covered in the Material Design specifications.

Comment: It just works as i wanted. Maybe true, but i don't ifnd better way to do that.